# VueJS - v-for and attributes on the parent Element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with a table display and am using vueJS to render a group of rows inside of a table. The bindings inside of the `<tr>` work fine, but I can't figure out how to bind say an attribute that lives on the parent `<tr>` that hosts the `v-for` directive:

```
<tr v-for="detailItem in itemList" data-key="{detailItem.pk}}">
        <td>{{detailItem.cdesc}}</td>
        <td>{{(detailItem.nnetunits * 1).toFixed(2)}}</td>
        ...
</tr>
```

In this code the inner items on the `<td>` bind just fine, but how would you get the `data-key` bound?

Answer (score 4):

With Vue 2 you don't use interpolation in attributes, you use the [attribute binding syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes).

```
<tr v-for="detailItem in itemList" v-bind:data-key="detailItem.pk">
```

Or the shortcut

```
<tr v-for="detailItem in itemList" :data-key="detailItem.pk">
```

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work for some reason (turns out some invalid data to bind). Retried now with valid data for the keys and it's working as expected. Thanks.